# Data table with pagination returns "No matching records found" error

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Initially data will be rendered in data table on clicking a button.

```
 <table id="result"  style="width: 1820px; height: 17px;" class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="" width="57" align="center" >No </td>
            <td class="" width="146" align="center" >Name </td>
            <td class="" width="323" align="center" >Desc</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="transactionInfo" varStatus="transactionIndex">                                                                                                                                 
            <tr>
                <td width="57"  >${transactionIndex.index + 1}</td>
                <td width="146"  >${transactionInfo.name}</td>
                <td width="323"  >${transactionInfo.Desc}</td>                                                                                                                                             
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

To load datable data in result div

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result').DataTable({
        searching : false,
        info : false,
        lengthChange : false,
        serverSide : true,
        processing : true,
        "ajax": {
                type : "POST",
                cache : false,
                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1256",
                async : true,
                url : "/MaintenanceController",
                data : buildSearchData,
                dataSrc : function(json){
                    return processResponse(json);
    
                }
        },
        deferLoading:57
    });
    });
```

This is the json data processing code, for now I had hardcodded the length & draw value.

```
function  processResponse(json){
    var dataTableData = {};
    dataTableData.draw = 1;
    dataTableData.recordsTotal = 57;
    dataTableData.recordsFiltered = 57;
    var dataTableRow = [];
    for( var i=0; i < json.length ; i++){
                                    dataTableRow.push([ i, json[i].name, json[i].desc] );

    }
    dataTableData.data  = dataTableRow;
    console.log("dataTableRow: "+JSON.stringify(dataTableData));
    return dataTableData;
}


function buildSearchData(){
//creating the request for ajax which works fine
}
```

console this is the data response

```
dataTableRow: {"draw":1,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57,"data":[["Test1","Test Desc1"],["Test2","Test Desc2"]]}
```

Error : Data table displays "**No matching records found"** error

Update :
After tried many possibilities,
On changing the return value like below of processResponse() loads the data in data table

```
 return dataTableData.data;
```

Here then how can I pass total records field ?

Comment: Hello. Is there any way you could try and reproduce your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: you have not provided complete information to see the problem, did you try `console.log` inside `processResponse` function, are you getting expected response from server check network tab in browser console ?